# Double execution of code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I run on Rails 4.2.0 with Ruby 2.0.0. I iterate over a model `Production.all` and call `production.finish!` in the .each loop.
My finish! method, at the end, deletes itself with self.destroy. But each undefined entry will be executed twice in the same loop.

```
def finish!
  self.progress = true
  self.save # that other crontabs can't access me anymore if the crontabs overlap

  if DeliveredProduction.find_by_production_id(self.id)
    # send me a notification, why this object still exists?
  else
    DeliveredProduction.create!(:production_id => self.id) # Each undefined times a get an Exception here because the production_id is already insert!
    # ...
    # do things here
  end
  self.destroy # my debug logs says that each entry was successful deleted
end
```

Is there any Bug in Rails 4.2.0 or Ruby 2.2.0p0? It only happens after 1-2 days that one is executed double. That code will be executed by a crontab. I also update all Production in the iteration with progress=true, so that later crontabs can't access this Objects. My debugging log says that the second execution of the same Production is in the same time (same second) a few seconds later.

Comment: Since you don't use explicit transaction, you can still get race condition before the `self.save`. It's not clear from your example where from `finish!` is called except that it is somehow a result of a cron job.

Comment: Maybe there are two identical entries in your crontab or the cron daemon is running twice?

Comment: Good hint @nic-nicolov
I will refactor my code to use transactions and will watch it.

Comment: Switching from an optimistic lock to a pessimistic one would help avoid race conditions. You just save `true` and *presume* it worked. That's where your problem is. Why not use a proper job queue for processing these?

Comment: Hey @MaikelUrlitzki! Did you manage to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `after_commit` callback for such things:

```
after_commit :deliver!, on: :update, if: ->{|me| me.progress}

def finish!
  self.update(progress: true)
end

def deliver!
  DeliveredProduction.create!(:production_id => self.id)
  self.destroy
end
```

`Model#save` doesn't guarantee that record will be saved when next line of code is executed. `after_commit` does. Just know the caveats of `after_commit`:

[Rails documentation on 'after_commit'](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods/after_commit)